# least mean squares(conditional expectation) problem

Tags: probability, estimation

The lifetime of a type-A bulb is exponentially distributed with parameter $2$. The lifetime of a type-B bulb is exponentially distributed with parameter $3$. You have a box full of lightbulbs of the same type, with an a prior probability of $1/3$ that the box contains type-B lightbulbs.Based on observing $T_1=2$, Find the LMS estimate of $T_2$, the lifetime of another lightbulb from the same box.

Because LMS is conditional expectation, I tried $$E[T_2|T_1] = E[A]P(A|T_1)+E[B]P(B|T_1)$$ But my answer is wrong, where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close.  What you want is:

$$\begin{align}
 & \mathsf E(T_2\mid T_1=2)
\\[1ex] = & \qquad(\text{by Law of Iterated Expectation})
\\[1ex] & \mathsf E(T_2\mid T_1=2, \mathrm A)\;\mathsf P(\mathrm A\mid T_1=2)+\mathsf E(T_2\mid T_1=2,\mathrm B)\;\mathsf P(\mathrm B\mid T_1=2) & 
\\[1ex]
 = & \qquad(\text{since expected life of bulbs in the same box are conditionally independent})
\\[1ex]
 &\mathsf E(T_2\mid \mathrm A)\;\mathsf P(\mathrm A\mid T_1=2)+\mathsf E(T_2\mid \mathrm B)\;\mathsf P(\mathrm B\mid T_1=2) 
\\[1ex]
 = & \qquad(\text{Using the Means of Exponential Distributions}) 
\\[1ex]
 & \tfrac 1 2\;\mathsf P(\mathrm A\mid T_1=2)+\tfrac 1 3\;\mathsf P(\mathrm B\mid T_1=2) 
\end{align}$$

Now, can you evaluate those posterior probabilities?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Till now we are in the same direction, so maybe I made the mistake on calculating $ P(\mathrm A\mid T_1=2) = 2/3*exp(-4)/(2/3*exp(-4)+1/3*exp(-6)) = 0.94$ Therefore, my final answer is $0.49$.Could you help me point out the problem?

Comment: Almost @QYang . The probability density function of an exponential distribution is $\;\mathsf f(X=x)=\lambda \mathsf e^{-\lambda x}\;$ so: .$$\mathsf P(\mathrm A\mid T_1=2) = \frac{\tfrac 2 3 \cdot 2\mathsf e^{-4} }{\tfrac 2 3 \cdot 2\mathsf e^{-4}+\tfrac 1 3 \cdot 3\mathsf e^{-6}} = \frac{ 4 \mathsf e^{2} }{ 4 \mathsf e^{2}+3 }$$

Comment: so the answer is $0.48$, isn't it? Maybe I misunderstood the exponential distribution conceptionally. Based on $\;\mathsf f(X=x)=\lambda \mathsf e^{-\lambda x}\;$, my lecture notes showed me $P(x>=a) = e^{-\lambda a}$. Could you give me a hint when I should keep $\lambda$ and when I just kick it out?